# Rails tip - "Use model association"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, controllers

So, I've read in some book about tip "Use model association", which encourages developers to use build methods instead of putting ids via setters.

Assume you have multiple has_many relationships in your model. What's best practise for creating model then ?

For example, let's say you have models Article, User and Group.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subdomain
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end

class Subdomain < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end
```

and ArticlesController:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # let's say we have methods current_user which returns current user and current_subdomain which gets current subdomain
    # so, what I need here is a way to set subdomain_id to current_subdomain.id and user_id to current_user.id
    @article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article])
    @article.subdomain_id = current_subdomain.id
    # or Dogbert's suggestion
    @article.subdomain = current_subdomain
    @article.save
  end
end
```

Is there a cleaner way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be `@article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article])`

Comment: @Dogbert: yeah, typo. tnx for noticing, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a little cleaner.

```
@article.subdomain = current_subdomain
```

Comment: true, but I'd like to avoid that whole line somehow. But still, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is merging the subdomain with params:

```
@article = current_user.articles.build(params[:article].merge(:subdomain => current_subdomain))
```

Comment: honestly, I tried that and for some weird reason, it didn't work.